# PDF JS: add JavaScript automatically to PDF during DOCX to PDF conversion

Tags: javascript, pdf, automation, ms-word, type-conversion

When I convert a Word to a PDF I would like to have JavaScript added automatically. 
The functionality like inks etc being kept during the conversation is very limited. Currently I need to add functionality to the PDF by means of JavaScrip manually to allow e.g. jumps to attached documents.
Is there any posibitly to automate that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it can be automated. You just need to be clever with how the JavaScript is written so that it's portable.

The Acrobat DC ribbon in Word includes an option to [Create PDF and Run Action](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/creating-pdfs-pdfmaker-windows.html) which will create the PDF file as normal and then immediately run an action on the new file. Actions can run JavaScripts and JavaScripts can be used to add buttons, links, bookmarks, etc to the PDF that also have JavaScripts associated with them. 
I have not started yet to look into the details but I assume you make basically use of the [Action Wizard](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html) by combining that with Adobes superior [create PDF function (instead of Microsofts save as pdf).](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1210689)